# PureComponent shallow compare on array state stil re-renders page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, components

How can I make the shallow compare of PureComponent to check if arrays are equal?

I have this class:

```
class Login extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      errorMsg: []
    }
  }

  signIn = async (fields) => {
   ......
    try {
      ......
      if (data.status === true) {
       ......
      } else {

        // error message is still the same after constant login fails
        this.setErrorMsg(`${data.msg}`);
      }

    } catch (error) {
     
    }

  }

  setErrorMsg(errorArr) {
    this.setState({ errorMsg: [errorArr] });
  }

  render() {
    ......
    {this.state.errorMsg.map((err) =>
        <Alert
         className="p-1"
         variant="danger"
         show={err}
         transition={false}
         key={err}
        >
        {err}
        </Alert>
    )}
    ......
  }
}
```

But after update of `this.state.errorMsg` with the same value, its still re-rendering, because `["Credentials is wrong"] === ["Credentials is wrong"]` returns `false`. How can I dynamically do a shallow compare on array state?

Answer (score 1):

That is how shallow comparison works. PureComponents are not meant for [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). You can pass a particular array element like `errMsg[0]`.

From the docs :

> Only extend PureComponent when you expect to have simple props and state, or use forceUpdate() when you know deep data structures have changed. Or, consider using immutable objects to facilitate fast comparisons of nested data.

Comment: I tried:

`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    
     return JSON.stringify(this.state.errorMsg) !== JSON.stringify(nextState.errorMsg);
  }`

What could possibly go wrong with this?

Comment: JSON.stringify(this.state.errorMsg) !== JSON.stringify(nextState.errorMsg); should return false. Is something else triggering the rerender?

Comment: exactly, I want it to return false inside the shouldComponentUpdate. But I think I have to go with the immutable js